# Angular modularization with dynamic route and dynamic dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, lazy-loading, angular-ui-router

I have a question about get routes and dependency of the main module dynamically. I've been researching this for over 3 days now and haven't found a satisfactory answer. I have found something which seems to come close but it's not what I'm looking for, I do not want to lazy-load my modules or just set routes dynamically .

so I will try to explain my needs as clearly as possible:
there is a folder that name is shared in my project that contains some reusable modules. I need my app.js to realize routes by drag and drop modules and dependency without manually change!

Does anyone have a solution for this?
Thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

This snippet can address your dynamic module resolution requirements.
create deps array and then pass it to "define" method (registered by requirejs).
put all of your related dependencies in the same folder. for each module, you can create a separate js file. every time that I need a new service, I create a separate js file for that service and place it to the 'services' directory and finally append the new service name to the dependency array. and new module is ready to use.

```js
(function () {
    (function (deps) {

        window.app.utils.appendPrefixToPaths(window.app.paths.services.out.get(), deps);

        deps.unshift("2.services/directive");
        deps.unshift("2.services/view");
        deps.unshift("2.services/preference");
        deps.unshift("2.services/alert");
        deps.unshift("2.services/materialDataTable");
        deps.unshift("2.services/security");
        deps.unshift("2.services/theme");
        deps.unshift("1.directives/_");

        define(deps, function (obj) {
            return obj;
        });

    })(window.app.services.fileNames.get());
})();
```